# How to set padding for gridview data with C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, padding

I have populated a gridview with C#, but the data in the girdview is very close to the cell borders. How can I take away the padding for the cell content with C#?

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM `fabrica`";

//'bd' and 'ExecuteRead' is my database classe
DataTable table = bd.ExecuteRead(query);
table.Columns["id"].ColumnName = "ID";
table.Columns["nome"].ColumnName = "Nome";
table.Columns["cidade"].ColumnName = "Cidade";
table.Columns["estado"].ColumnName = "Estado";
table.Columns["telefone1"].ColumnName = "Telefone 1";
table.Columns["telefone2"].ColumnName = "Telefone 2";
table.Columns["telefone3"].ColumnName = "Telefone 3";
table.Columns["email1"].ColumnName = "Email 1";
table.Columns["email2"].ColumnName = "Email 2";
table.Columns["email3"].ColumnName = "Email 3";
Tabela.DataSource = table;
Tabela.ControlStyle.Width = 885;

Tabela.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CellPadding property.

```
Tabela.CellPadding = 10;
```

Reference : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.cellpadding.aspx

Comment: Are you using some built-in style for Grid View? or Grid View container override your Grid View style.

Comment: If I'm not wrong, that auto format override your CellPadding value.

Comment: It's okey, I'm solved with css, because I don't have any other solution